# Powershell New-NetFirewallRule with -LocalUser example

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall, rule

How to create Firewall rule which will be impacting only one of the local accounts

In theory below example would be sufficient however Im missing value for parameter "-LocalUser"

Below PowerShell command

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "BLOCKWWW" -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 80,443 -Protocol TCP -Action Block -LocalUser **WHATGOESHERE**
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging from [the examples showing how to use other parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps#examples) with similar descriptions (like `RemoteUser`), it'll take a discretionary ACL in SDDL with a single entry per user.

You could write a small helper function to generate these based on username:

```
function Get-FirewallLocalUserSddl {
  param(
    [string[]]$UserName
  )

  $SDDL = 'D:{0}'

  $ACEs = foreach($Name in $UserName){
    try{
      $LocalUser = Get-LocalUser -Name $UserName -ErrorAction Stop
      '(A;;CC;;;{0})' -f $LocalUser.Sid.Value
    }
    catch{
      Write-Warning "Local user '$Username' not found"
      continue
    }
  }
  return $SDDL -f ($ACEs -join '')
}
```

Then use it like:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "BLOCKWWW" -LocalUser (Get-FirewallLocalUserSddl user1,user2) -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 80,443 -Protocol TCP -Action Block
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = new-object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount ("corp.contoso.com\Administrators")
$SIDofSecureUserGroup = $user.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
$secureUserGroup = "D:(A;;CC;;;$SIDofSecureUserGroup)"
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.